# Has anyone succesfully installed windows 7 on a system with a low amount of ram?

Tags: windows-7, memory, requirements

The system requirements from Microsoft about Windows 7 [outline](http://windows.microsoft.com/systemrequirements) a minimum 1 gb for a 32 bit installation.

Does anyone have any advice, tips, success or failure stories about trying to get it running on a older machine that doesn't meet the outlined requirements?

Example cases; would 768mb work but be annoying to use, 512mb be really difficult to install, 256mb not even worth trying?

Comment: I had Aero running on an Atom, integrated graphics, and 1GB ram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 scale really well to low-end hardware. I have installed Win 7 x32 on a Pentium 4 Celeron 2.2GHz with 384MB memory, and it was perfect for basic tasks like Office, iTunes, Web, etc etc.

Win 7 has been optimized quite thoroughly, and most user experience states that they are pretty impressed with how well performance scales across different hardware.

Give it a shot - any machine within the past 5 years should work well.

Comment: And hey, right now Win 7 is free to try out for 90 days anyway! Download the Enterprise version and give it a whirl to see how you like it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=sprblog

Comment: whether it makes sense to buy a $100 OS for an old clunker that's worth $20 at a yard sale is a different story altogether :)

Answer (score 3):

In fact people have done

> W7 runs on a P2 with 266MHz CPU, 96MB
>   RAM & 4Mb graphic card ! i have done 3
>   tests: 2 successfull…
>   1. 128 MB RAM
>   2. 96 MB ram

See here [Running Windows 7 on a Dinosaur](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/06/running-windows-7-on-a-dinosaur/) if you don't believe it yourself

Comment: Does Vista/Win7 work on the original (586) Pentium?

Answer (score 2):

There is one reference on [Windows Seven 7 Runs Flawlessly on 512MB RAM](http://mintywhite.com/tech/windows-7/windows-seven-7-runs-flawlessly-on-512mb-ram/).
And a [512MB VM installation reference](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=672).

Another [local question reference](https://superuser.com/questions/17917/which-windows-7-to-install) -- it is about selecting x32/x64 for a 2GB RAM system though.
Also if you feel interested an Atom 1GB RAM install: [Windows 7 - What I saw in 15 minutes](http://www.kudzuworld.com/Blogs/Tech/20090115.en.aspx)

Comment: I have to admit I haven't installed Windows 7 on 512MB, but have a few 2008 R2 servers in VM's running 512MB without much hassle.

Comment: i'm sure some boffins will make windows 7 run on 64 MB if they only tweak hard enough. just as it is possible to run XP on a downclocked 7 MHz CPU with as little as 20 MB RAM. :) http://www.winhistory.de/more/386/xpmini_eng.htm

Answer (score 0):

The installer fails to install if the machine has less than 256 MB ram.

Comment: I believe it (also) refuses to install if the machine has less than ~384 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed W7 on 512MB systems several times - works just fine.