# Oldest PC running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I run Windows 7 Ultimate (RC) on a four year on a Pentium 4, 2.8 GHz machine with 1GB. It is totally responsive, and my steady state memory usage is around 512MB.

So I was wondering if anyone had experience of running Windows 7 acceptably on older hardware.

Comment: I asked a similar question focusing on the amount of RAM required: http://superuser.com/questions/36238/has-anyone-succesfully-installed-windows-7-on-a-system-with-a-low-amount-of-ram

Comment: Windows 7, as I understand it, is designed to run on the same hardware as Windows XP.

Comment: There is no reason Windows 7 wont run on any 80386 processor or higher.  Obviously, RAM is the biggest factor.  Swapping on extremely low memory machines and on a slow disk would give horrendous performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [The Windows Club](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-hardware-devices/28053-windows-7-dinosaur.html), someone claims to have run Windows 7 on a circa-1997, 266MHz Pentium II with 96MB RAM and a 4MB video card, but it took 17 hours to install and booted in 17 minutes...

A Pentium III with 512 MB should already perform much better as claimed by NeoWin:

> At Windows fan site Neowin.net,
>   testers have claimed success with a
>   700MHz Pentium III ThinkPad with 256MB
>   of RAM and a 600MHz Pentium III
>   desktop with 512MB of RAM.

Check [this link](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9136192/Windows_7_How_low_can_you_go_) for more reports on less legacy hardware running Windows 7

Comment: That's one incredibly long vacation! I want one too :)

Comment: This is where I was hoping the discussion would go. I have a 350MHz PII, with 90MB of RAM. Now I'll be tempted to try installing Win7 on it.

Comment: I went to Italy (Rome!) for 2 weeks and before and after it some days off... Sadly not much internet so no superuser... but I'm still in the third place!

Comment: But you forfeited the Enthusiast or Fanatic badges :P

Answer (score 1):

I was running the Beta at almost-acceptable speed in a VBox VM on a host P4 2.4 with 1GB RAM. I'm sure it would have run fine outside the VM on the same hardware.